# After Resuming from Sleep, Second SATA HDD Visible, But Not Accessible

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1, sleep, sata, dell-inspiron

Second SATA HDD is Visible, But Not Accessible after Resume from Sleep.

Dell 15r 7520

Windows 8.1x64 - Fully Updated

C Drive - OS Drive. Kingston mSATA SSD

D Drive - 2nd Drive: WD Blue 1TB SATA

The WD Blue is not accessible after resuming from sleep.
It is visible in the device manager and in My Computer.

In My Computer, I can click on it and it will show the Documents folder, which will open to show a list of folders, but when I click on any of these they will not open.

After a few mins I get the following error message - D:\Documents\Books is not accessible, The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.

If I restart all is working again.
When I do restart after this problem it takes approx 2 minutes, normally 30/40 secs.

In the Device Manager I tried Scan For Hardware Changes - no change.

In Power Options, I set - Turn Off Hard Drive to Never - no change.

BIOS is up to date.

I tried legacy and UEFI boot settings.

I enabled USB Wake Support - it was disabled.

I scanned the WD Drive using WD Diagnostics - all fine.

[Error Message I get after I click on a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8juuv.png)

[BIOS SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPgzW.jpg)

[Power Options Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80FOo.png)

Comment: Try installing the Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver and reboot.>>>>https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/55005

Comment: Installed the RST from Dell for the 7520 SE. The HDD disappeared. RST did tell me that the WD Blue had a password, ( I thought the pw was for the SSD) so I removed the password and this solved the problem.

Comment: You should answer your own question below and post it.